# Android canvas - Drawing arc between to points and removing arc from path

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-gesture

In my android application, i want to provide tracing letter feature as shown in following image :

[image]

Here i want to provide tracing of letter-D and for that i need to draw arc between two points when user starts moving finger on arc. Here, if user starts moving finger from start point and stops at end point then only it should draw arc between those points. And it should also show arc while moving finger on arc path.For that i have written below code.The problem i am facing is that, when `ACTION_UP` event is fired on arc path, it still shows arc drawing on canvas. But i want to remove that drawing from path if it fires `ACTION_UP` event in between of arc path.

Here is my code :

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

List<Point> pointsD = new ArrayList<Point>();
pointsD.add(new Point(520, 70));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 335));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 70));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 335));

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
      if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex)) {
                mPath.reset();
            isPathStarted = true;
          } else {
            isPathStarted = false;
      }
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

    if (isPathStarted) {
        mPath.reset();
        Point p = null;
         p = pointsD.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            float radius = 1;
        RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(scalePointX((int) (486 - radius)),scalePointY(70),                               scalePointX((int) (686 + radius)),
                        scalePointY((int) (334 + radius)));
        if (sweepAngelD <= 180 && startAngleD <= 360) {
            mPath.arcTo(oval, startAngleD, sweepAngelD, true);
        sweepAngelD += 1;
        startAngleD += 2;
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
    mPath.reset();
}

private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
       mPath.reset();
            if (isPathStarted) {
                float radius = 1;
                RectF oval = new RectF();
                oval.set(scalePointX((int) (486 - radius)),
                        scalePointY(70), scalePointX((int) (686 + radius)),
                        scalePointY((int) (334 + radius)));
                Point p = pointsD.get(mLastPointIndex);
                mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                mPath.arcTo(oval, startAngleD, sweepAngelD, true);                  
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                mPath.reset();
                ++mLastPointIndex;
            } else {
                sweepAngelD = 1;
                startAngleD = 270;
                mPath.reset();
             }
            isPathStarted = false;
 }

private boolean checkPoint(float x, float y, int pointIndex){
if (pointIndex == pointsD.size()) {
            // out of bounds
            return false;
        }
        point = pointsD.get(pointIndex);
        // EDIT changed point.y to poin.x in the first if statement
        if (x > (point.x - TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
                && x < (point.x + TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
            if (y > (point.y - TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
                    && y < (point.y + TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: :please help me,what is scalePointX,scalePointY method in the code?thanks

Comment: @arash this method will maintain coordinate values of each point according to different device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I edited my code as below and now it is working..

```
    public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

List<Point> pointsD = new ArrayList<Point>();
pointsD.add(new Point(520, 70));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 335));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 70));
    pointsD.add(new Point(520, 335));

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
      if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex)) {
                mPath.reset();
            isPathStarted = true;
          } else {
            isPathStarted = false;
      }
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

    if (isPathStarted) {
        mPath.reset();
        Point p = null;
         p = pointsD.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            float radius = 1;
        RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(scalePointX((int) (486 - radius)),scalePointY(70),                               scalePointX((int) (686 + radius)),
                        scalePointY((int) (334 + radius)));
        if (sweepAngelD <= 180 && startAngleD <= 360) {
            mPath.arcTo(oval, startAngleD, sweepAngelD, true);
        sweepAngelD += 1;
        startAngleD += 2;

    }
    mPath.reset();
}

private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
       mPath.reset();
            if (isPathStarted) {
                float radius = 1;
                RectF oval = new RectF();
                oval.set(scalePointX((int) (486 - radius)),
                        scalePointY(70), scalePointX((int) (686 + radius)),
                        scalePointY((int) (334 + radius)));
                Point p = pointsD.get(mLastPointIndex);
                mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                mPath.arcTo(oval, startAngleD, sweepAngelD, true);                  
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                mPath.reset();
                ++mLastPointIndex;
            } else {
                sweepAngelD = 1;
                startAngleD = 270;
                mPath.reset();
             }
            isPathStarted = false;
 }

private boolean checkPoint(float x, float y, int pointIndex){
if (pointIndex == pointsD.size()) {
            // out of bounds
            return false;
        }
        point = pointsD.get(pointIndex);
        // EDIT changed point.y to poin.x in the first if statement
        if (x > (point.x - TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
                && x < (point.x + TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
            if (y > (point.y - TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
                    && y < (point.y + TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: How were you able to accomplish the whole thing? I have a TextView which displays the letter for tracing but I am not sure how to implement the Canvas on top of it to allow users to draw.

Comment: I have created png images to display letter for tracing and draw that bitmap image on canvas. After that i drew points on screen for different co-ordinates, then i handled touch functionality on points, as you can see in my code.

Comment: I got the letter to be displayed using custom font in my App but how did you get the `1` and `2` to show up?

Comment: @zanky:what is scalePointX,scalePointY method in the code?thanks

Comment: @arash this method will maintain coordinate values of each point according to different device.

Comment: Hello @zanky it wold be great helpful for me if you prove step by step procedure.