# How to draw a graphics in view on android platform

Tags: android

[image]

I want to draw a view like the picture above，but I'm stuck in how to draw the outline, I can only draw a circle, I cannot add two ears ，so someone can help me, I also want to draw a progress.

Comment: You can use `Path` to draw lines.

Answer (score 1):

Draw line it just

```
   @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //canvas.drawLine(sx, sy, fx, fy, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
    }
```

If you are asking how to draw an arc, then you really need to [use the Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888650/android-canvas-drawing-arc-between-to-points-and-removing-arc-from-path). 
or this code:

```
    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
    p.setStrokeWidth(5);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 100, 80);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, p);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true, p);
```

Comment: i want to know how to draw that outline.

Comment: then you really need to use the Path

Comment: I don't know the algorithm

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-touch-interaction--mobile-19202